# Loop multiplying values by itself

Tags: python

I am trying analyze some data from wiki. I am trying to append some values from one column of a data frame to a blank list based on condition from another column from the same data frame. length of new list should come to 34 but it is coming to 1632. Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_wiki=requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_helicopter_prison_escapes#Actual_attempts")
def data_from_url(url,tag_name,class_name):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('HTTP 404: Page not found')
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        html_output = soup.find(tag_name,{'class':class_name})
        output = pd.read_html(str(html_output))
    return output[0]

escape_data=data_from_url("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_helicopter_prison_escapes","table","wikitable")

escape_data[['Date', 'Year']] = escape_data['Date'].str.split(',', expand=True)

escape_data = escape_data[['Date', 'Year', 'Prison name', 'Country', 'Succeeded','Escapee(s)','Details']]

Years_Succeed=[]

for year in escape_data['Year']:
    for i in escape_data['Succeeded']:
        if i!='Yes':
            continue
        else:
            Years_Succeed.append(year)
```

Comment: You have nested loops over the dataframe, which creates a cross-product.

Comment: I think you just want `years_succeed = escape_data[escape_data['Succeeded'] == 'Yes']['Year'].to_list()`

Comment: Wooh it solved in one line. Thanks a lot Barmar

Comment: Is this for loop technique wrong here, or it can be corrected?

Comment: In general, if you're looping over a dataframe there's likely to be a better way using pandas built-in techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `Year` and `Succeeded` on the same row

```py
for year, i in zip(escape_data['Year'], escape_data['Succeeded']):
    if i != 'Yes':
        continue
    else:
        Years_Succeed.append(year)
```

Or with list comprehension

```py
[year for year, i in zip(escape_data['Year'], escape_data['Succeeded']) if i == 'Yes']
```

But the most convenient is Pandas way

```py
escape_data[escape_data['Succeeded'] == 'Yes']['Year'].to_list()

# Or

escape_data.loc[escape_data.index[escape_data['Succeeded'].eq('Yes')], 'Year'].to_list()
```

Comment: Thank you all. Much appreciated. got multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: how do i get here counts of years. i.e. for year 1986 there are 3 values. so my list looks like this: 1975 - 1, 1986 - , 1987-1, etc.

Comment: @JitendraGahalot Check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments noted, you want to do

```
years_succeed = escape_data[escape_data['Succeeded'] == 'Yes']['Year'].to_list()
```

to avoid looping on a dataframe.